# One Disk on two SATA ports for full performance

Tags: ssd, sata

I want to connect my 860 evo SSD with 550MB/s to my PC and actually utilize all the performance. My Motherboard only has SATA II ports (300MB/s). Is there a way to use two SATA ports for one SSD to unlock the full 550MB/s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You may be able to get a PCI SATA card to give you higher speed. That said, are you sure the SATA ports are 300 megabyte? I would have thought a motherboard that is that old would not be a good candidate for eeking speed out if an SSD.  That said, even at 300 megabyte its a worthwhile upgrade - 3 times the sequential speed but a huge latency reduction for random access and wait times.

Comment: BTW, there are [port multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier) for SATA (even though SATA it is "serial"), so I was wondering if there's some kind of "port aggregator" that takes different ports at lower speeds and passes them on at a higher speed... Probably not, as not many people would buy one, but it should be possible in theory. (Though I agree that a PCIe SATA card is probably the practical solution).

Comment: @dirkt ta. TIL....

Comment: thanks. Yes, I'm sure, the motherboard only has SATA II as per manufacturer specification. I'm upgrading either way, for the reasons you mentioned, and also when eventually I upgrade the whole PC I'm able to utilize the full performance of SATA III (almost..)

Answer (score 0):

You may partially succeed if you buy two half-capacity 860 EVO SSDs (that should be about two times cheaper), connect then to your ports and setup a RAID-0 one or another way.

I understand the advice is not helpful if you need to use exactly the single SSD you have in your hands but would work if you are only bound to our motherboard and budget for buying ***a*** SSD 860 EVO (these come in capacities from 250 Gb to 4 Tb).

It may be more hardware limitations on your board that would limit the total throughput to less than 300+300.

Comment: neat idea, but I think the mobo's built in raid won't be faster than SATA II (I might very well be wrong here, it's just my intuition. could be that the RAID controller has more throughput.) so I would have to buy a raid extension card that would be able to handle the throughput but at that point I can just buy a SATA III extension card. Also I already have the SSD so getting two with half the capacity each is no option either.

I've come to accept that I'll just have to use SATA II on my board until I get a new one that probably has SATA III anyway.

Comment: No, RAID 0 configuration provides close to double throughput and the capacity is the sum of capacities of both drives. Under Linux you could use the same two ports without additional hardware. But if one drive fails in RAID 0, you lose data in both.

Comment: I know RAID 0 but I'm not sure how the RAID controller on the mobo is connected, and whether it would actually result in a higher throughput